# Cannot create stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures

I have the following piece of statement entered into MySQL5.6 Command Line Client. However, the following error was received. I haven't even been able to add in END// Delimiter; after the select statement.

At the same time, i was wondering after the stored procedure has been created successfully, how do i CALL the stored procedure without the command line but using java codes.

Kindly assist. Greatly appreciated!

[image: Error]

Comment: this is purely related to database then why java tag here

Comment: Move this to: http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @raffian I have flagged it for  dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: hihi, im trying to find out how would i be able to write java codes from netbeans/ eclipse to call the stored procedure as well. Thus not writing any prepared statements or sql statements from netbeans. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mysql> delimiter //

mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE GetUStocke()
-> BEGIN
->   SELECT * FROM buystocks ;
-> END//
```

Comment: hihi, lets say i have used the sql command line to create this stored procedure successfully. How do i replace it with the typical sql statement that i write on my java pages so that i could call on the stored procedure written?

Answer (score 3):

give space between `delimiter` and `//`. After your `select` statement write `end;` on next line and `//` at last line (after `end;` in next new line)

```
delimiter //
create procedure GetUStocks()
Begin
Select * From buystocks;
end;
//
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a space between DELIMITER and the symbol you are changing the delimiter to.

```
mysql> DELIMITER //
```

The clue that it worked should be that you get another `mysql>` prompt instead of the "unfinished command" prompt `->`.

---

Re your comment, if you need to call a stored procedure from a Java application, refer to the manual on callable statements: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-j-usagenotes-statements-callable.html

Comment: hihi, lets say i have used the sql command line to create this stored procedure successfully. How do i replace it with the typical sql statement that i write on my java pages so that i could call on the stored procedure written?

Answer (score 0):

Well, seriously, I was Shocked and still am upon this accidental discovery.
It's simply because you are not using the delimiter that you have defined for ending the procedure.
Here let me attach two snippets that will help illustrate what is generating the error.

[image: Screenshot]